# Ajax call to different website returns html instead of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to receive an array using an `.ajax` GET request to a URL.

Here's my controller, hosted locally on `localhost:3000`

```
def merchant_ids
  merchants = Merchant.where(id: params[:id]).pluck(:merchant_name, :id, :merchant_city, :physical_address, :merchant_phone, :latitude, :longitude)
  render json: merchants
end
```

If I make a request the following way:

```
$.ajax('http://localhost:3000/dashboard/merchants/merchant_ids/1').done(function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

it logs the array just fine.

But if I try to do the same thing from another app using `localhost:3001` it returns
[image: description]

the whole html view instead of the array.

what am I doing wrong here?

I have `gem 'rack-cors'` and the config:

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '/*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Ajax call try putting ContentType and dataType as json

try this-

```
    $.ajax({
         url:"http://localhost:3000/dashboard/merchants/merchant_ids/1",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

Because you are trying to access the json data on callback, you need to specify the dataType of the returned data .. Also specify this along with your ajax request..

dataType: "json",

Comment: that works, but now this happens: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/dashboard/merchants/merchant_ids/1. The request was redirected to 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.`

Comment: ok, I was able to just add `before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:merchant_ids]` and now it's working correctly, thank you very much!